# Herkou site looks different at launch then django local server site

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

My issue is that when I view my site using `python manage.py runserver` or `foreman start`, I can see my site perfectly.

However, when I `git push heroku master` on the surface everything appears fine as no errors are given. But when I view my site with the Heroku given site link, I do not see my updated site as I see when I view my site using `python manage.py runserver` or `foreman start`.

I am building my site using 'pinax-theme-bootstrap` and my virtualenv is on my desktop directory.

Does anyone have a solution as to why this may be the case?

Comment: Did you remember to `git add` and `git commit` before pushing to Heroku?

Comment: are you sure you are commiting on the branch that tracks heroku's master?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of suggestions on how I would approach this issue with Heroku.

1. You should try `heroku restart`. This restarts your application and can help pick up new changes.
2. I would  clear my browser cache as often I do not see changes on my web page if the browser has cached them.
3. I would check that the git repository on Heroku matches my local one in that it has all the newest changes made on my local server.